# Android O NotificationChannels default category

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I recently added a category to my notification categories and I was able to set what I wanted into that category. However, another category is showing in lists of these categories under "uncategorized" which I believe it's the default category, image below:

[image]

Any idea how I can delete that category?
If it's bad practice to delete it, why is that?

Comment: Do you target API 26?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot that I took was from an Android O device and my compileSdkVersion is set to 26.

Comment: No, I asked about `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: Interesting. I have multiple Android O apps targeting API level 26 and do not see "Uncategorized" in notifications.  I do, however, see "Miscellaneous" category.  Please try uninstalling your app, verifying that every `notification` that you create in your code has a valid category, and then build & run your app again.  Please let us know the result.  Also, which Android O build version did you load?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I had my targetSdkVersion at 25, so I set it to 26, deleted my app, build + clean, re run my app, and I ended up with the same "Uncategorized" category.

Comment: @CzarMatt I noticed that it says "Miscellaneous" on a real device but it says "uncategorized" on the emulator. I only have one notification and that one has the category that I manually added and that was intended. What do you mean by Android O build version? like the preview?

Comment: Based on your observations between emulator and real device, it seems like "Miscellaneous" ("Uncategorized" for emulators) is the default.  This can be cross-checked with the fact that all other pre-installed apps seem to have this default category as well.  I don't see a way to remove/override in the Notification docs.

Comment: @CzarMatt I don't see one either. I'm assuming probably the default behavior is to have at least two categories that's why the system is prompting that category, but again that's an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same issue but only while my `targetSdkVersion` was 25. It went away after I updated it to 26.

Comment: I had my targetSdkVersion at 25, so I set it to 26, deleted my app, build + clean, re run my app, and I ended up with the same "Uncategorized" category.